# pexpect child.before problems with Cisco IOS, not getting result from command

Tags: python, ios, cisco, pexpect

So I've been working all night on trying to solve this problem, and i can't seem to find a solution. 
I'm telneting into a cisco 7200 router and trying to get the state of a couple of BGP connections and for some reason i'm only getting the beginning of the prompt as a result. More information on what is failing in the comments in the code.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('telnet %s' % (host.gethostname()), maxread=16384)
#child.logfile = sys.stdout
#child delaybeforesend = 0
child.timeout = 200

child.expect('Username:')
child.sendline(username)
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect('#')

#we should now be inside the router, time to find out what version it is running
print "Trying to detect router version"

child.sendline('show version')
status = child.expect(['#','--More--'])
tmp_holder = child.before <------- succesfully retrieving the router version information.

if status == 1:
     child.sendline('q')
     child.expect('#')

if "7200 Software" in tmp_holder:
     print "---Router Version CISCO 7200 Detected---"
     print "---Checking BGP status---"

     for neighbor in host.getbgpip():
         child.sendline('show bgp all neighbors %s ' % (neighbor))
         bgp_status = child.expect(['#', '--More--'])
         bgp_status_holder = child.before # <---this part is failing, not getting the return from show bgp all neigbors

         if bgp_status == 1:
            child.sendline('q')
            child.expect('#')

         if 'Established' in bgp_status_holder:
             print host.gethostname()+" established to "+neighbor
         elif 'Idle' in bgp_status_holder or "Active" in bgp_status_holder:
             print host.gethostname()+" not established to "+neighbor
         else:
             print host.gethostname()+" non existing neighbor: "+neighbor
         print bgp_status_holder
         #child.interact() <---if i activate this i get the result printed, plus i'm seeing the "--More--" that i'm trying to catch above.
     child.close()
```

If i use child.after when trying to set the bgp_status_holder variable instead of child.before i only get # as the result.

Comment: If the indentation is wrong it's only because i tried to indent the code better here on stack overflow so it would be easier to read, the indentation is not wrong anywhere in the actual code( this block is behind a couple of try's and therefor more indented). But thanks for pointing it out! I fixed it here to make sure that the code is clear :)

Comment: Just a tip: send `terminal length 0` command and you'll get the full output without pagination (`--More--` stuff).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i found the problem and it was, as it normally is, a brain fart on my side, i'm using pexpect and expecting #, but the show bgp all neighbors contains a # in the text.